# Puppet: how to enforce a certain file extension for the tempfile when using validate_cmd

Tags: validation, puppet, consul

I'm using puppet to generate consul config files. I'd also like to validate the files using `validate_cmd`. Unfortunately puppet generates file names like `my-service.json20171026-6787-5on04g` but `consul validate` requires a `.json` extension.

How can I force puppet to generate temporary files with a `.json` extension?

```
file { "${consul_clientconfig_dir}/${name}.json":
  ...
  content      => template("${module_name}/template.json.erb"),
  validate_cmd => "${consul_binary_dir}/consul validate %",
  notify       => Exec['consul_reload']
}
```

I'm using consul 1.0.0 and a pretty olde puppet version 3.8.

Comment: This resource would generate a `.json`. Where is the resource that generates the odd extension?

Comment: @MattSchuchard the final file has a `.json` extension, right. But with `validate_cmd` a temporary file (with the odd extension) is created and used for the validation step.

Comment: Ok, got it. Unfortunately, the answer seems to be no because https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/60ee26915e0381be5246ae9ddebc518b63554bd9/lib/puppet/type/file.rb#L875 is nested inside https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/60ee26915e0381be5246ae9ddebc518b63554bd9/lib/puppet/type/file.rb#L856. Unlike `backup`, there is no option to specify the extension for the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems currently not be possible (see @MattSchuchard comment above).

Luckly, with consul 1.0.1 comes the [`-config-format`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_config_format) option which does not answer my initial question but solves my problem.